# Why are the InitParams I pass into Silverlight always empty?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, initialization

My Silverlight application needs one parameter, an integer. In my Html, I have written:

```
<param name="InitParameters" value="UserId=1" />
```

In code I am reading the parameters in:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in e.InitParams)
{
    Resources.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value);
}
```

e.InitParams is always empty. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because I'm passing in "InitParameters" instead of "InitParams". That's what I get for staring at my code for too long.

Comment: Thanks, I did the same stupid mistake. Your answer solved me hours of frustration!